# osm2pgsql get_way failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, linux, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to import OSM Europe to postgresql under Debian.
If I am importing only e.g. Czech Republic, then import is successful. But if I try to import Europe then I always got an warnings and error:

> Going over pending ways...
> 247747782 ways are pending
>
> Using 4 helper-processes WARNING:  terminating connection because of
> crash of another server process DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded
> this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit,
> because another server process exited abnormally and possibly
> corrupted shared memory. HINT:  In a moment you should be able to
> reconnect to the database and repeat your command. WARNING:
> terminating connection because of crash of another server process
> DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back
> the current transaction and exit, because another server process
> exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory. HINT:  In a
> moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your
> command. WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another
> server process DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server
> process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another
> server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
> HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and
> repeat your command. WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash
> of another server process DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this
> server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because
> another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared
> memory. HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the
> database and repeat your command. node cache: stored:
> 1121820464(40.68%), storage efficiency: 71.32% (dense blocks: 192000,
> sparse nodes: 0), hit rate: 39.09% Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR:
> get_way failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.

Here is my script:

```
osm2pgsql -d gxreverse -E 4326 --verbose --flat-nodes flat-nodes --keep-coastlines --cache 12000 --hstore --hstore-add-index --tablespace-index pg_defaul
t --unlogged --cache-strategy dense --extra-attributes --slim -S default.style reducedAll.osm.pbf
```

I tried to change settings cache and other properties, but still same result.

What can I do?